# C#: Как я могу проверить, использует ли клиент официальное приложение?

Tags: c#

У меня есть tcp клиент/сервер. Когда клиент подключается к серверу, IP клиента записывается на сервере и используется для передачи данных через рандомные IP адреса клиентов этой сети клиентам сети.
Эта система не защищена и выходит так, что каждый сможет внести свой IP на сервер, просто подключившись к нему.
Если это будет происходить, то кто нибудь сможет записать множество IP адресов, через которые нужный трафик не сможет достичь валидных клиентов сети.
Как решить эту проблему? Возможно, стоит в корне изменить структуру? Вообще, идей у меня нет.

P.S: видел в интернете множество примеров, в которых используется ssl сертификат X509, но везде проверку на сертификат можно обойти, убрав одну строку в коде клиента, да и по сути, это совсем не то, что нужно.

Comment: По сути, никак. Любой человек может декомпилировать клиентское приложение, поменять его логику и откомпилировать снова. Вы можете лишь затруднить это, усложнив взлом протокола общения (шифрование? аутентификация?) и декомпиляцию (вынести критические части в нативный код).

Comment: 100% защиты не существует, курите в сторону шифрования с открытым ключом, или протокол Диффи-Хельмана что по сути примерно одно и тоже, при передаче шифруете, при приеме расшифровываете, структуру пакетов изменять при этом не потребуется...

Comment: При первой передачи сервер, например может отправлять запрос и знать какой ответ прийдет, клиент получает запрос(рандомный), прогоняет его через определенный алгоритм и возвращает ответ, если ответ верен, то и клиент - официальный, так работают Hasp ключи